# UIAlertView button to take you to another view in tab bar controller

Tags: ios, uialertview

Hello I am currently working on an app which uses a tab bar controller. In the tab bar controller I have 3 views. The third view has a button that when pressed it gives the user an Alert. When the user presses the button ok in the Alert, I would like the user to be redirected to the first view in the tab bar controller. I have tried the following to no success, I'm not sure if it is possible. I have also left my other findings just in case I was on the right track but did not notice. Thank you in advance!

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{
    //DetailClassViewController *view = [[DetailClassViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailClassViewController" bundle:nil];
    //UINavigationController *testNavi = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view];
    //self.window.rootViewController = testNavi;
    //[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    DetailClassViewController *controller=[[DetailClassViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailClassViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

}
}
```

Comment: when you have a UITabBar all the view controllers are already instantiated. also, you don't use modal transitions between tab bar controllers, as far as I know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply use:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

I hope it would help.